# how to solve MSBUILD : error MSB4132 on windows 10?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, msbuild, windows-10

I'm working in a project in angular2 , and now I am using windows 10 . After execute npm install I got this error:
MSBUILD : error MSB4132

> MSBUILD : error MSB4132: The tools version "2.0" is unrecognized.
>   Available tools versions are "12.0", "14.0", "4.0". gyp ERR! build
>   error gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1 gyp ERR!
>   stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
>   gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
>   C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\n
>   ode-gyp.js" "rebuild" gyp ERR! cwd
>   C:\Users\wcatalan\Documents\clinica\AppMovilMemoria\tools\Visual
>   Studio Code\MemoriaIonicAuth\node_modules\microtime gyp ERR! node -v
>   v7.10.0 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.5.0 gyp ERR! not ok.

I tried to fix it, installing the "builds tools" of visual studio, but nothing. In windows 7 I never had this error. Any idea?, in this moment everything helps

Answer (score 27):

Maybe this can help: 
https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/629#issuecomment-153196245

If not, you can also try to install from windows CMD in admin mode this package:

```sh
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

Comment: This worked for me, but only after I executed the following command:
"npm config set msvs_version 2017"

Comment: I get the following error when executing: `Downloading installers failed. Error: TypeError: 'process.env' only accepts a configurable, writable, and enumerable data descriptor` (using node 18.13.0)

Answer (score 8):

This chocolatey package solved the problem for me:

```
https://chocolatey.org/packages/visualstudio2017buildtools
```

If you already have chocolatey installed then just type:

```
choco install visualstudio2017buildtools
```

If you don't:

```
https://chocolatey.org/install
```

Answer (score 5):

It's trying to install something that needs to be C++ built using node-gyp. Have you followed the instructions at https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp for installation on Windows? If not, that would likely fix your issue.

Comment: I followed the instructions but I dont know why it didnt work, I "fix" it, changing the version of ionic and cordova, it was using the version 3.x.x of ionic and I changed it for 2.2.3, and reinstall everything, following the instructions again. Whit the command npm uninstall ionic it did not work for me if somebody has the same problem, I used npm -g uninstall ionic. Thanks to both.

Comment: Had some similar problem, after I ran the "npm install --global --production windows-build-tools" command, also had to run "npm install --global node-gyp", thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled npm and installed an earlier version, specifically this one: 
https://nodejs.org/download/release/v5.3.0/node-v5.3.0-x64.msi

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Windows Command Prompt with Administrator Privileges:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
npm config set msvs_version 2012 --global
```

How to run PowerShell as Administrator? See below

[image: run PowerShell as Administrator]

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was using the wrong version of nodejs.
I had to [install nvm](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-node-version-manager) to manage multiple versions of node, then switch to the compatible version (node 14.20.0 in my case).