# ng serve gives un expected errors

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I am running the `ng serve` command , and it is giving unexpected errors.

the errors are:

```
PS C:\Users\SAYED-SADAT\Desktop\data\coding\itsm-frontend\itsm-frontend> ng serveYour global Angular CLI version (13.0.3) is greater than your local version (10.1.6). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
[Browserslist] Could not parse C:\Users\SAYED-SADAT\Desktop\package.json. Ignoring it.
10% building 3/3 modules 0 active(node:14892) [DEP0111] DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 1.85 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 686 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.js, scripts.js.map (scripts) 12.3 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 239 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 339 kB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2021-11-29T06:54:58.534Z - Hash: 388a52fd9471c8c66792 - Time: 1115ms

ERROR in ./node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--13-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-4!./node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/index.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Node Sass version 6.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0.
    at getSassImplementation (C:\Users\SAYED-SADAT\Desktop\data\coding\itsm-frontend\itsm-frontend\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\utils.js:84:13)
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\SAYED-SADAT\Desktop\data\coding\itsm-frontend\itsm-frontend\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:34:59)

ERROR in ./src/assets/sass/app.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--13-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-4!./src/assets/sass/app.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Node Sass version 6.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0.
    at getSassImplementation (C:\Users\SAYED-SADAT\Desktop\data\coding\itsm-frontend\itsm-frontend\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\utils.js:84:13)
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\SAYED-SADAT\Desktop\data\coding\itsm-frontend\itsm-frontend\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:34:59)

ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.9.2 and <4.1.0 but 4.4.4 was found instead.
```

Note: when I downgrade the typescript version `TypeScript >=3.9.2 and <4.1.0` it still gives the errors.

Comment: What are node.js and node-sass versions?

Comment: node 16.13.0 sass 4.14.1

Comment: other projects works fine, but it is not working in this project

Comment: try to downgrade your node by uninstalling it, and install older version, like node 14 or 12

Comment: or try to upgrade your node-sass to latest version

Comment: Change your versions to `node.js-14` and `node-sass: "4.14.1"`

Answer (score -1):

I think you might be able to find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57216110/the-angular-compiler-requires-typescript-3-4-0-and-3-5-0-but-3-5-3-was-found). Looks like it is a comprehensive guide on similar issues.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).